# Copying code from one machine to another creates stray characters

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors, makefile, gedit

I copied C++ code from one machine to another using a thumb drive. The code works fine in the first machine, however in the second machine it gives me errors saying there are stray values in the code.

I use [gedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedit) for both and both the machines have the same version of Ubuntu. I tried converting each of the text files in my second machine to a different format using:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ucs-4 <globalFns.h>/dev/null
```

But it did not work. Using *[cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix))* or *[vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)* for the files on the second machine produces some unrecognizable characters. But doing the same in the first machine gives the actual C++ code.

What am I missing?

Comment: git solves this issue. Use git.

Comment: Including examples of the code (from both machines) is going to be of use here.

Comment: I am using git..It does not give a stray error but gives me a different error..the program contains over 50 C++ files and using git it says "no rule to make target..."

Comment: I can't give examples from the code because as I mentioned it is huge.over 50 C++ files

Comment: I solved it!It's in the summary as well but I had to change the PT variable in the make file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
This was the code from the first machine's makefile:

```
 PT = ../Code

 #include gccmac.mk
 #include gcc.mk
 #include icc.mk
 #include bcc.mk
 #include PC-lint/pclint.mk
```

Had to change the PT variable to point to the right dir.

Thanks for the help.